# Delete row with multiple TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

If I have 2-3 TableView, how can I disable 'Delete' row only for the specific TableView? When I set breakpoint for if statement to check which tableView is used, it's not working

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.firstTableView {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            firstTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            firstTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set editing mode to false in viewDidLoad for secondTableView but it's not working also.

```
secondTableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
```

I understand that by default it's set to false, so I thought if `commit editingStyle` enable it for all tableViews, so I can disable it for second.

Answer (score 1):

Just give each `TableView` a tag and check it in an `if` or `switch` statement.

```
if tableView.tag == 0 {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this also. It's not working. Anyway both TableView have swipe Delete option.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to disable delete in editing mode or to not have a delete button when sliding left on a cell?

Comment: Not have a delete button when sliding left.

Comment: I would use `editActionsForRowAt` and only return the actions you want for each tableView, checking the tags with an if statement. I can update my answer with an example if that will help.

Comment: Thank you very much but I have already provided the correct answer and @Nikhlesh Bagdiya has already did the same.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is checking for tag in `editingStyleForRowAt indexPath`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if tableView.tag == 1 {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        // Return false if you do not want the specified item  or table to be editable.
        if tableView == tableVw {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
  }
```

Here tableVw is a `tableview` object which you want to not editable or you can also use tag instead of object compare.
Then use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {

           //Write your delete cell logic here
           array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
           tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
           tableView.reloadData()
         }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm not sure if I should put this as a correct answer since I have already answered on my question with the same info.

Comment: You have to use canEditRowAt tableview function as I mention above and then check its work or not

Comment: yes, this is logical to implement delete functionality first. I thought there is no sense to say it in my answer, so I just posted the answer where the real magic happens. Thank you anyway!